# Send setState("") as function to new component

Tags: reactjs

I have a probably simple React question. I´m trying to pass a function to another component where I want to set state to empty(""). Can you see why it won´t work for me. Earlier I setState("") in the Component by I´d like to do that in Mainfile instead...

Thanks,

Mainfile:

```
<GenerateData
  data={CustomerData}
  numbers={numbers}
  setData={setCustomerData("")}
/>
```

Component:

```
interface IProps {
  setData: (party: string) => void;
}

<button onClick={() => setData}>
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail how the three snippets relate to each other? It's a little unclear what the interface is for, where the button lives, and what the function result of `setCustomerData` is (assuming void return based on name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setData={setCustomerData("")}` you call `setCustomerData("")` and pass the result of the function to the child component, i.e. `setData` = `undefined`

```
<GenerateData data={CustomerData} numbers={numbers} setData={setCustomerData} />;

interface IProps {
    setData: (party: string) => void;
}

<button onClick={() => setData('')}>
```